# Add commas to every three digits in the number which is in float format

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, nsstring, nsnumberformatter

I have a float number in a string, I need to add commas to every three digits of the number.

Here is what I had tried,

```
NSString *mystring =@"20090809.99";
float fl = [mystring floatValue];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSLog(@"%@ ", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fl]]);
```

I need the result as `20,090,809.99`. What should I change in my code?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877055/how-to-convert-currency-in-word-spell-in-iphone/11877450#11877450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
NSString *mystring =@"20090809.99";
NSNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:mystring];    
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSLog(@"Formatted float: %@ ", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code for doing this task:-

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter1 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString * formattedAmount2 = [formatter1 stringFromNumber: @20090809.99];
    NSLog(@"%@",formattedAmount2);
```

It's OUTPUT is :-

**20,090,809.99**

Comment: `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` already enables grouping separators (at least in some locales; I don't know if it is locale-dependent). This code fixes the problem because it calls `-stringFromNumber:` directly, rather than passing the data through a limited-precision `float`.

Answer (score 2):

without number formatter:

```
NSNumber *someNumber = @(1234567890);
NSString *modelNumberString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", someNumber];
NSLog(@"Number with commas: %@", modelNumberString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting code is correct. The problem is that your number is of type `float`. Type `float` has limited precision. Your number cannot be represented exactly by `float`. The `float` value closest to `20090809.99` is `20090810.00`. That is what `-floatValue` returns so that is what gets printed.

If you change your variable to type `double`, and call `-[NSString doubleValue]` and `-[NSNumber numberWithDouble:]`, then it will behave as you expect.